# jquery draggable the entire div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When using draggable, how can I grab the whole div and not just the words in the div?

```
<div id='something'>
   <ul>
      <li class='draggable' id='frank'>Frank</li>
      <li class='draggable' id='Joe'>Joe</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id='somethingElse'>
   <div class='dragme' id='yes'>Yes</div>
   <div class='dragme' id='no'>no</div>
</div>

  $(function() {
      $( "li" ).draggable();
      $(".dragme").draggable();
  });
```

Here is my JSFiddle

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/so3tckfr/3/)

Comment: The div itself is already draggable in the fiddle you provided. 
Do you want to make the items inside non-draggable?

Comment: when dragging, i want to see a box. with some yellow background and the text inside.  right now, when i drag, it is only the text itself.

Comment: I think I am missing something, but do you mean [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/75hLyk8r/1/)?

Comment: @Damon no, what i mean is the div that the word "yes" is in, or the <li> that the word Frank is in

Answer (score 0):

Add the draggable class to the DIVs you want to drag, and remove it from the LI elements:

```
<div class='draggable' id='something'>
    <ul>
        <li id='frank'>Frank</li>
        <li id='Joe'>Joe</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br>
    <br>
        <div class='draggable' id='somethingElse'>
            <div id='yes'>Yes</div>
            <div id='no'>no</div>
        </div>
```

Then call `.draggable` on everything that has the draggable class.

```
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable").draggable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the containers draggable, not the list items:

```
$("#something, #somethingElse").draggable();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/so3tckfr/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just call `.draggable()` on the top-level element which you want to be draggable. 
I would recommend using a special class (see Tony Hinkle's answer), but without changing your HTML code, it would be:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#something, #somethingElse" ).draggable();
});
```

Or if you want to select containers based on the fact that they contain elements of specific class, then use [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
$(function() {
  $( "div:has(.dragme), div:has(.draggable)" ).draggable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#something").draggable();
$("#somethingElse").draggable();
```